# AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' has no attribute 'DatasetsPair'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter, imblearn, smote

I'm trying to balanced my data on jupyter-notebook, using SMOTE:

```
from imblearn import over_sampling
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE
balanced = SMOTE()
x_balanced , y_balanced = balanced.fit_resample(X_train,y_train)
```

but I'm getting the following error on the first line -

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.metrics._dist_metrics' has no attribute 'DatasetsPair'
```

Why am I getting this error?
thanks.

Comment: what version of imblearn are you using? 

`import imblearn`

`print(imblearn.__version__)`

Comment: I can't print it. it says ```NameError: name 'imblearn' is not defined``` .

Comment: interesting. what about `python3 -m pip show imbalanced-learn` ?

Comment: @omerk Are you sure, that you did not forget `import imblearn` first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reinstall scikit learn to version 1.1.0. That should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error while importing modules from skforecast package

```
from skforecast.model_selection import grid_search_forecaster
from skforecast.model_selection import backtesting_forecaster
```

Reinstalling scikit-learn to version 1.1.0 or 1.0.0 worked with additionally restarting the jupyter server.

Answer (score -1):

update sklearn

```
conda install -c anaconda scikit-learn
```

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.